# BLE-TxPower spec to DBM

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The eddystone protocol defines the TxPower to follow the specification https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.tx_power_level.xml&u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.tx_power_level.xml

But how do I convert a value of 0xDF to dbm using that range?

Also, I see no relation on 0x12 being +18 and 0xEE being -18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple relation called [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

0xDF = -33dbm

Hope it helps.

UPDATE:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-flash.html

Comment: I mean trough that spec. Since 0xEE = -18, how 0xDF can be -33?

Comment: It is a signed 8-bit (two's complement) representation 0xEE = 0b11101110 = -18 whereas 0xDF = 0b11011111 = -33

Comment: Well, right, i gonna try work with that, but the device is configured to transmit -12dbm so i tought 0xDF should be it.

Comment: If you have 0xDF, then it is set to -33dbm. For -12dbm it should be 0xF4

Comment: Well, thanks for the 'Two's Complement', I gonna accept this answer as correct.